# Alter jsonlog data

Tags: 9

I am looking to alter the generated output of the log files from the contrib module JsonLog - https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonlog/
The logger generates a .log file, which I need to customize with a few additional fields.
Is there a way to alter the data generated by the Logger class? What is the best approach for this?
Is extending the Logger within a custom module a good approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loggers in Drupal are Symfony services, so the best way to modify this is to *decorate* the [logger.jsonlog service](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/jsonlog/-/blob/3.x/jsonlog.services.yml) (you need a custom module to this of course). I'd suggest   starting with the [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html) or google'ing for `symfony decorate service` to get some code examples.